# Getting issue in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented jquery UI autocomplete.Mouseover is working properly on list but when I use down arrow key it display id also in text box which I don't want as given below:
for example id 119 is displaying in below image.

[image]

What can I do now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look on the doc : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem
The "_renderItem" allows you to customize the displayed list.

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .attr( "data-value", item.value )
    .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
    .appendTo( ul );
}
```

Edit : here is a complete code I use to display both ID and item name in the list :

```
$("input.project-code").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: availableProjects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            $(this).change();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.value + " - " + item.name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: Actually in my case when I use down arrow key id value is displaying but I don't want that So what I have to do for that?

Comment: I think you can have a look on this part of the code :
`focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },`

Comment: The `focus:` part allows you to choose what to put in the input when you focus an item with your arrow keys